# what is the way to extract string in javascript

Tags: javascript

the data is like this /Canada/Quebec/Montreal or /Japan/Osaka/ or /USA/California/Sanfransico

and I want to extract only country name which is right after first /.

The result should be Canada, Japan and USA

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `substring` operation would look something like this:

```
var data = '/Canada/Quebec/Montreal';
var country = data.substring(1,data.indexOf('/',1));
```

So basically take the string, exclude the first character up to the next occurance of `/` after the first index.

Answer (score 3):

You can split the string on slash and take the second item:

```
var country = data.split('/')[1];
```

You can also locate the second slash and use `substr`:

```
var country = data.substr(1, data.indexOf('/', 1) - 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var thestring = '/Canada/Quebec/Montreal';

console.log(thestring.split('/')[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var country = str.slice(1, str.indexOf('/', 2))
```